# deleting value from Circular Linked List

Tags: java, circular-list

There is a problem with my code, after I delete the node, the same node appears as previous node in the next node.
Trying to remove node 4.

Pervious: Node: 5; Node: 15; NextNode: 16 |
Pervious: Node: 15; Node: 16; NextNode: 29 |
Pervious: Node: 16; Node: 29; NextNode: 4 |
Pervious: Node: 29; Node: 4; NextNode: 5 |
Pervious: Node: 4; Node: 5; NextNode: 15 |

After removing

Pervious: Node: 5; Node: 15; NextNode: 16 | 
Pervious: Node: 15; Node: 16; NextNode: 29 |
Pervious: Node: 16; Node: 29; NextNode: 5 |
Pervious: Node: 4; Node: 5; NextNode: 15

```
public Node deleteValue(int i) {
    Node node = start;
    do {
        if (node.next.getData() == i) {
            Node n = node.next;
            node.next = n.next;

            size--;

            if (n == start) { 
                start = node;

            }
            return n;
        }][1]

        node = node.next;
    } while(node != start);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does your Node class have a field/variable that points to the previous Node? Or does it only have the next field pointing to the next element?

Comment: Yes I have Node prev;

Comment: Well, then you probably modify that in your remove method. You are currently only changing the next attribute. So it should come as no surprise that the prev attribute stays the same and still points to the removed element.

Comment: but how cause i don't have any idea???????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete you item, you are missing a simple line of code. You must set your previous element's next element, and the next-next element's previous element.
You are actually missing the second part.
This is what the code should look like :

```
Node current = start;
do{
  if(current.getData() == i){
    // set the previous's next element
    current.previous.next = current.next;
    // set the next element's previous element
    current.next.previous = current.previous;
    this.size--;
    return current;
  }
  current = current.next;
}while(node != start);
return null;
```